# Playing again by the same player after hitting the net

Tags: rules, volleyball

After receiving the service the ball hits the net. It is legal to continue as long as you are within the 3 hits limit.

But can the same player continue after hitting the net? Player 1 hits the net, the ball bounces, and then the same Player 1 continues by passing to another team member?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed. [The official rules](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf) say:

> 9.1.1 CONSECUTIVE CONTACTS
>
> A player may not hit the ball two times consecutively (except Rules 9.2.3, 14.2 and 14.4.2).

Let's have a look at these exceptions:

> 9.2.3 The ball may touch various parts of the body, provided that the contacts take place simultaneously.

This situation is not simultaneous, so this exception doesn't apply.

> 14.2 BLOCK CONTACT
>
> Consecutive  (quick  and  continuous)  contacts  with  the  ball  may  occur  by one or more blockers, provided that the contacts are made during one action.

> 14.4.2 The first hit after the block may be executed by any player, including the one who has touched the ball during the block

Since this isn't about blocking, these exceptions don't apply either.